# Need ctype_digit to return true for negative numbers also

Tags: php

I need to take a string and return true if only positive OR negative numbers are in the string. Is there a way to do this?

```
$rating = "-25";
if (!ctype_digit($rating)) {
echo "Not a digit.";
} 
else {
echo "Is a digit.";
}
```

**Result:**

Not a digit.

**Need Result:**

Is a digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ctype_digit()` works on values that consists *only* of digits.
Where `$rating = -25;` is false as it is being treated as a ASCII code in this particular case (explained below), and `"-25"` is invalid because `-` is not a digit.
You could type juggle but I think you're looking for [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

`echo is_numeric( "-25");` or `echo ctype_digit((integer) $var);`

However the latter would return true if the string cannot be cast to an integer. It will have the value of 0 if that's the case.

**Important:**
If you pass a literal integer in range of `-128` and `255` to `ctype_digit()` the value is converted to the character defined in the ASCII table. If its not a number, false is expected. Any other integer value is normal expected behavior.

Comment: "works only with real integer numbers" this is just wrong. ctype_digit works for number in strings.

Comment: @modu You are right, I've edited to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

[filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) is the correct answer to this question and has been around since 5.2, according to the documentation.

filter_var will return filtered data or `false` if the string is not a valid integer.

```
var_dump(filter_var("1", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false);
var_dump(filter_var("0", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false);
var_dump(filter_var("-1", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false);
```

Result:

```
test.php:1:boolean true
test.php:2:boolean true
test.php:3:boolean true
```

Note that you must perform a comparison with `false` instead of logical `!` otherwise it will fail when comparing with `0`.